# Fusion 360 - Unexpected behavior when using deboss on curved surface

Tags: cad, software

I'm including the example file. On one side, the text is debossed as expected. Using the same process for the other side, "Educate, Equip, Empower", the boss seems like it's coming at an angle and squishing the letters in the middle.

[Award Ring](https://a360.co/3A2geQv)

Comment: This is a common problem in cad applications. Reason being that fonts generally arent usually terribly well designed from a technical standpoint. they are designed strictly for 2D but they frequently have errors that are not big priblems in a printer, but huge problems once you try to build a offset boundary surface out of them. try removing q qnd i and see if it works now.

Comment: It looks to me as if the difference is due to the shape/curvature of the ring - the top line of text looks fine on both sides.

Comment: I’m going to try to deboss the shield shape and then emboss the text in separate steps and see if that changes the behavior. Thank you both for the insight.  I manually traced the font to create the profile because I have had similar problems with raw text in the past.